# Has anyone tried to return a protobuf object from C++ to Java through JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, protocol-buffers

I have a Java code, which calls into native C++ code through JNI. Today the result produced by the C++ code is returned as an XML string.

I would like to replace it with a Protocol Buffers object.

Now, I have two options after producing the PB object:

- Serialize it to a string and return it
- Try and return the object itself.

Has anyone tried the second option? Will it work? Any potential problems with it?

Thanks.

Comment: It should work, but it will be much slower than translating the data directly. i.e. it could be so much slower that you might as well programmed the whole thing in Java.

Comment: by second option you mean casting a C++ PB object to java `jobject`? I don't think it will work. I think your only option is serializing it to bytes in jni side, return the byte array to java and deserializng there. Or create java object and fill it in c++ side.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - what do you mean by the whole thing? I cannot throw away the native DLL and surely I cannot rewrite it in Java.

Comment: Serializing and deserializing data can be fairly expensive. Whether you can or should replace the DLL depends on why you are using it. If it's purely for performance reasons, using serialization could kill the benefit you get.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - no, it is not for performance reasons at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear about what is meant by "*Protocol Buffers object*". I assume that you mean the message object, generated from *.proto* file by `protoc`. Then i dare to say it won't work. While the PB *serialization form* is indeed cross-platform and cross-language, the *implementation* isn't. While you can call methods on Java objects in C(++) thanks to vast array of C functions provided by JNI, there is no reverse interface to do the same from Java (on C++ objects).

But anyway, the PB objects are nothing more than an instrumented structs. The instrumentation is useful only for PB serialization. If you won't use the serialization, PB is essentialy useless for you. If your XML has at least somewhat stable structure (PB won't accomodate unkown structure anyway), why don't you reflect it in plain Java object, pass it on C++ side over JNI and fill up there, using all the JNI functions mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one have to serialize an object with `SerializeToArray(..)` and pass the bytes as byte array or buffer. See how it works [here](https://github.com/4ntoine/JniBenchmarking/blob/0447e8d26dec0d9293cad3abbec1b9d2842e9e52/engine/src/main/cpp/libengine.cpp#L152).

Comment: External links are okay, but they might break over time. What would be great is if here we could have a self-contained code sample explaining how to deal with the problem